# How to use rank() function with duplicate scores but without skipping rank?

Tags: microsoft-excel

By default, the rank function in Excel gives duplicate numbers the same rank but for the next score it will skip a rank. So if there are 2 scores on rank 5, the next score will get rank 7.

I want to use a function that will give the same scores the same rank but without skipping a rank. 
See following example:

```
Score   rank
60       1
60       1
55       2
49       3
38       4
38       4
32       5
```

So the scores get a rank from high to low and there is no gap in the ranks.

Comment: you will need to modify my formula in the link a little to work as that does the ranking in ascending order.  First change all the A1 references to A2 as you have a title row the original did not and change the `...A1>=...` to `...A1<=...`

Comment: @MátéJuhás and Scott: thanks a lot! This solved my problem. Indeed, changing the >= to <= made the sorting order descending.

Answer (score 0):

Copy column **A** into column **D**; sort the data descending and then remove duplicates.  Then in **B2** enter:

```
=MATCH(A2,D$2:D$9999,0)
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Comment: You also need to make sure that the column D is sorted descending.  Just in case column A is not.

Comment: Thanks for your input but it's no option for me to copy the data as I need to keep the rank after each round so would need lot of extra colums.